# How can I obtain a vertical bar that fills, like a progress bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, sharpdevelop

As the title says I'm trying to obtain a vertical a bar and fill it depending on values. I couldn't apply any answers I found. One answer suggested replacing System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar with a class name but that renders my design view unusable. What can I do?

EDIT: I need a bar like that for somthing like a graph report showing how many ppl are at work from the total number of employes.

Comment: Whats wrong with the standard progress bar?

Comment: Grab a picturebox and increase it's width every update.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg In this case the height should be increased since it's vertical. Good ideea.

Comment: @VanTalk ah sorry I misread:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a vertical progress bar control.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile and drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class VerticalProgressBar : ProgressBar {
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 4;   // Turn on PBS_VERTICAL
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a more customized look then simply derive from Control instead, add a Value property, and override the OnPaint() method to draw it any way you like.

Comment: Thank you! I've seen the code before but didn't understood what to do with it. " Compile and drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form." - in Sharp develop it appears in the Tools > Custom Components section - but you got me knowing better where to look.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to implement your own control, you will find all you need in the `System.Drawing namespace`. Just use `Rectangle` objects (one frame and one progress). Fill the inner progress rectangle to show progress by manipulating its height via a value property.

If you don't know how to draw, check this out:
[How to: Create Graphics Objects for Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-graphics-objects-for-drawing?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Or just use the `ProgressBarRenderer` class to manipulate the frameworks progressbar your way. This class has a `DrawVerticalBar()` member. On MSDN you even find a complete example for a vertical bar, I think.

MSDN should be your first place to go when coding .NET apps and you need some basic how-to info.

Comment: Helpful info, thanks, except that the article you linked is in German

Comment: Thank you. This was not my intention. I have fixed it.